# AnimationController smooth stop in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, animation, dart

I have a spinning object in my flutter-app.
When the user clickes on it, it is supose to slow down until it's stopped 100%.
I can't make this happen, how do I do somthing like that?

```
 AnimationController angleController;

  slowDown () {
    setState(() {
      rotationSpeed += 180;
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        slowDown ();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    angleController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: rotationSpeed));
    angleController .addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        angle = angleController.value * rotationAngle / 360 * pi * 2;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CurvedAnimation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) and choose the [Curve](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html) that better fits your needs.

```
animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeIn);
```